# Ran the Craft Updater from Control Panel the current install is no longer working

Tags: install, manual-updates

The previous install (3.0.34) was working fine until I ran the updater from the CP. The update failed with error (couldn't access web.config (IIS))

Now loading CP or front end displays the following error:
Warning: require(C:...Craft\Projects\Untye/vendor/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/web.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\rickn\Documents\Craft\Projects\Untye\web\index.php on line 20

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:...\Craft\Projects\Untye/vendor/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/web.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:...Craft\Projects\Untye\web\index.php on line 20

Is there a way to finish the install manually and keep the previous work and data?

`{`
"require": {
   `"craftcms/cms": "3.0.35",`
 "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.4.0",
    `"craftcms/redactor": "^2.1",`
"craftcms/mailgun": "^1.3",
   `"craftcms/contact-form": "^2.2",`
"indigoviking/liquid-letters": "^1.2",
    `"lukeyouell/craft-contactformtemplates": "1.0.1",`
"doublesecretagency/craft-bootstrap": "4.1.1.2",
   `"fatfish/navigation": "1.0.7",`
 "superbig/craft3-templateselect": "^2.0",
   `"craftcms/ckeditor": "1.0.0-beta.2",`
 "verbb/navigation": "^1.0",
   `"enupal/slider": "1.2.2",`
 "studioespresso/craft-dumper": "^1.3",
   `"topshelfcraft/wordsmith": "^3.0",`
 "craftcms/craft": "^1.0"
 `},`
 "autoload": {
 `"psr-4": {`
    "modules\": "modules/"
  `}`
 },
 `"config": {`
   "optimize-autoloader": true,
 `"platform": {`
     "php": "7.0"
  `}`
 },
 `"scripts": {`
  "post-root-package-install": [
 `"@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""`
   ]
 `}`
}

Comment: If you have ssh access, try running composer update.

Comment: Thanks. Then I get - The requested package craftcms/cms (locked at 3.0.34, required as 3.0.35) is satisfiable by craftcms/cms[3.0.34] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

Comment: Update your composer.json line that says 3.0.34 to 3.0.45

Comment: Still getting the original error in the question

However this time composer returned Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "modules\Module" was found in both "$baseDir . '/modules/Module.php" and "C:/...vendor/craftcms/craft/modules\Module.php", the first will be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running
    composer update
Via the command line while in ssh

Or download the latest Craft files and replace your files. Mainly vendor/craftcms it looks like.

Edit:

Update composer.json to this and try running composer update again.

```
{
  "require": {
    "craftcms/cms": "^3.0.35",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.4.0",
    "craftcms/redactor": "^2.1",
    "craftcms/mailgun": "^1.3",
    "craftcms/contact-form": "^2.2",
    "indigoviking/liquid-letters": "^1.2",
    "lukeyouell/craft-contactformtemplates": "1.0.1",
    "doublesecretagency/craft-bootstrap": "4.1.1.2",
    "fatfish/navigation": "1.0.7",
    "superbig/craft3-templateselect": "^2.0",
    "craftcms/ckeditor": "1.0.0-beta.2",
    "verbb/navigation": "^1.0",
    "enupal/slider": "1.2.2",
    "studioespresso/craft-dumper": "^1.3",
    "topshelfcraft/wordsmith": "^3.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "modules\\": "modules/"
    }
  },
  "config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "platform": {
      "php": "7.0"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
      "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Replacing vendor/craftcms I then get
yii\base\ErrorException: include(C:\...\Craft\Projects\Untye\vendor\composer/../craftcms/redactor/src/Field.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\...\Craft\Projects\Untye\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.phpyii

Comment: Can you add your composer file to your question?

Comment: Added in the composer.json code

Comment: Updated the json. give that a shot.

Comment: Thanks, get

C:\Users\rickn\Documents\Craft\Projects\Untye> composer require craftcms/craft
Using version ^1.0 for craftcms/craft
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating optimized autoload files
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "modules\Module" was found in both "$baseDir . '/modules/Module.php" and "C:/Users/rickn/Documents/Craft/Projects/Untye/vendor/craftcms/craft/modules\Module.php", the first will be used.


And no change to  original error

Comment: This is a local server setup, correct? I'm not as familiar with possible issues they could have. Could you possibly start over on this install? Just a suggestion. Otherwise, I would send in a support request to Craft and have Brad look at it. I'm just basing my suggestions off of typical update/install errors I have on non-local setups. (btw, thanks for using my plugin!)

Comment: Have a lot of work that I'd hate to lose. I'll send a request to Craft, thanks for trying to help and for the plugin!

Comment: Following your lead, updated composer.lock file to 3.0.35 and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! Usually some combination of the right version numbers will fix the issue.